# enter query string in textfield on webpage, click submit and get query results back

Tags: javascript, node.js, spring, angular, spring-boot

I am looking for a generic way to pass any query string (from any oracle table, NOT hardcoded) from a webpage form/field to database and make the webpage display table/grid of the results. All examples i have seen so far require hardcoding columns/table name upfront in CRUD apps on github. I would like to be able to get results from various tables each with different columns, data types. I dont want the tables/columns hardcoded in the app. I have been using SpringBoot so far to accept any query string in POST req and return results as list of json records but i want to make it more interactive, easy to use for casual users so seeking some examples for simple textfield input and dynamic results grid.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Knex.js: https://knexjs.org/

It's a query builder that works with different databases. Here's a little sample from their doc:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'oracle'
});

function handleRequest(req, res, next) {
  query = knex.select(req.body.columns).from(req.body.table);

  console.log(query.toString()); // select "c1", "c2", "c3" from "some_table"
}

// Imagine this was invoked from Express and the body was already parsed.
handleRequest({
  body: {
    table: 'some_table',
    columns: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
  }
});
```

As you can see, the inputs are just strings which can come from anywhere, including clients/end-users. Just be careful that the user that's connecting to the database has the appropriate grants (least privilege applies here).

Comment: I dont want to hardcode column names. Need something like http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/ but with output grid not hardcoded cols and input being a sql.

Comment: That was just an example, the inputs can come from anywhere. I've updated the answer with an example that makes that more clear.